# Facebook OAuth redirect_uri problem 'Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.'

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

When asking for authorisation by redirecting to the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=144921372242843&redirect_uri=http://localhost:18080/grails/facebook/facebookLogin&scope=user_about_me
```

Facebook returns the error message (in JSON):

> Invalid redirect_uri Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.'

If I change the port number used in `redirect_uri` from 18080 to 8080 it works fine. Does anyone know which ports Facebook will accept (and why)?

Comment: I would like a more detailed answer, considering I'm using port 3000 for a rails app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said somewhere in configuration, to be able to "test" your application on localhost, you need to use port 8080. I really see no reason why would you use 18080, used for PureMessage manager

Comment: I tried using port 80 instead, but that generates the same error. It seems port 8080 is the only one that works

Comment: "As said somewhere in configuration"- what does that mean?